# Cannot able to use libxml++ from eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, libxml2

I need to add libxml++ to my project. The libxml [page](https://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/stable/) says to use the following way to compile the code.

```
g++ program.cc -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6`
```

I tried it from terminal and the code was compiling. But I would like to build the code from eclipse. Hence i added `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6` to `project->properties->C/C++ build->settings->g++ compiler->miscellaneous->otherflags`. After adding, when i tried to build i am getting ERROR. Here is my build output.
make all

```
Building file: ../src/main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -E -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 'pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6' -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
g++: error: pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6: No such file or directory
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

What am i doing wrong? Please enlighten me.

Comment: I use this: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt

Comment: @Galik your solution worked partially. still i am having build error.

Comment: @Galik it worked perfectly. Can you mention this as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For libraries that use `pkg-config` I use this `Pkg-config` plugin for `eclipse`:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt

Select the package you want for each project from:

`Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings`

Select the `Pkg-config` tab.

[image]